# Viewport is off DirectX 11

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, directx, directx-11

My viewport in D3D11 is off. Here is the code:

```
CoreWindow^ Window = CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread();
D3D11_VIEWPORT viewPort = { 0 };
viewPort.TopLeftX = 0.0f;
viewPort.TopLeftY = 0.0f;
viewPort.Width = Window->Bounds.Width;
viewPort.Height = Window->Bounds.Height;
viewPort.MinDepth = 0.0f;
viewPort.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
```

By off I mean that it is not starting from 0,0 on the app's window. Instead I think it is starting from 0,0 on my monitor.

Comment: Well try to set viewPort.TopLeftX and viewPort.TopLeftY to Window->Bounds.Left and Window->Bounds.Top respectively, to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: No, it is not working. The view port stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure You
In DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC Provide the HWND to the Output Window Member of this struct, keep Windowed = true
Even Then if you have this problem, While making Windows Have you aligned the Client Region correctly?
Make sure that you align the client region Correctly with the non-client region.

```cpp
RECT rt = {0, 0, 640, 480};
AdjustWindowRect(&rt, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE);
```

Now while creating window, specify your width as

```cpp
rt.right - rt.legt \\ For Width
rt.bottom - rt.top \\ For Height
```

This adjuses your client region with non client.

Even Then you have this problem. Check this Out
"https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/viewports-and-clipping"